# What does "Unaware of its limitations, it flies anyway" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I guess there is some irony in the sentence in bold. Can somebody explain it for me, please?

> Failure recedes and obstacles disappear in the “you can do it” spirit of the company symbol, the bumblebee—a creature that, according to mythical aerodynamics experts, should not be able to fly. **Unaware of its limitations, it flies anyway**. —[Source](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=lCAlDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=Failure+recedes+and+obstacles+disappear+in+the+%E2%80%9Cyou+can+do+it%E2%80%9D+spirit+of+the+company+symbol,+the+bumblebee%E2%80%94a+creature+that,+according+to+mythical+aerodynamics+experts,+should+not+be+able+tofly.+Unaware+of+its+limitations,+it+flies+anyway.&source=bl&ots=uRuY27eGL0&sig=ACfU3U1n7T18Z_uYUM_13428F1DLmTpQew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiamYig_9ThAhWEad4KHV2kCEwQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Failure%20recedes%20and%20obstacles%20disappear%20in%20the%20%E2%80%9Cyou%20can%20do%20it%E2%80%9D%20spirit%20of%20the%20company%20symbol%2C%20the%20bumblebee%E2%80%94a%20creature%20that%2C%20according%20to%20mythical%20aerodynamics%20experts%2C%20should%20not%20be%20able%20tofly.%20Unaware%20of%20its%20limitations%2C%20it%20flies%20anyway.&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous sentence says that "mythical" experts in the science of flight say that the bumblebee ought not to be able to fly. The part you asked about uses sarcasm to attack those mythical (imaginary, non-existent) experts, by saying that the bumblebee is unaware of their opinions, and, as a result, flies. The piece is from a business-motivational book. The idea being expressed is that by ignoring experts who tell you that you can't do something, you become able to do it. There are a number of logical flaws in this view, which I shall not go into here.